# MSVC generates needless copies for a struct with a byte array inside

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Pd8hjjxn7

Given the following piece of code:

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    alignas(__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__) std::byte _value[16];
};

Foo fByRef(const Foo&);

Foo gByRef(const Foo& input) {
    const Foo intermediate1 = fByRef(input);
    const Foo intermediate2 = fByRef(intermediate1);
    return fByRef(intermediate2);
}

Foo fByVal(Foo);

Foo gByVal(Foo input) {
    const Foo intermediate1 = fByVal(input);
    const Foo intermediate2 = fByVal(intermediate1);
    return fByVal(intermediate2);
}
```

Clang (`-O2 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17`) generates the following code for `gByRef`:

```
        sub     rsp, 40
        call    fByRef(Foo const&)@PLT
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rdx
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 16]
        call    fByRef(Foo const&)@PLT
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdx
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    fByRef(Foo const&)@PLT
        add     rsp, 40
        ret
```

but MSVC 19.33 (`/O2 /DNDEBUG /std:c++17`) generates:

```
$T1 = 32
$T2 = 32
intermediate1$ = 48
intermediate2$ = 64
__$ArrayPad$ = 80
__$ReturnAddress$ = 112
input$ = 120
Foo gByRef(Foo const &) PROC                        ; gByRef, COMDAT
$LN4:
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 96                             ; 00000060H
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR __security_cookie
        xor     rax, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rsp], rax
        mov     rbx, rcx
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]
        call    Foo fByRef(Foo const &)       ; fByRef
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR intermediate1$[rsp]
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movdqa  XMMWORD PTR intermediate1$[rsp], xmm0
        call    Foo fByRef(Foo const &)       ; fByRef
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR intermediate2$[rsp]
        mov     rcx, rbx
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movdqa  XMMWORD PTR intermediate2$[rsp], xmm0
        call    Foo fByRef(Foo const &)       ; fByRef
        mov     rax, rbx
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rsp]
        xor     rcx, rsp
        call    __security_check_cookie
        add     rsp, 96                             ; 00000060H
        pop     rbx
        ret     0
Foo gByRef(Foo const &) ENDP
```

Instead of directly passing the address of `intermediate1` to the second call, MSVC introduces a temporary variable on the stack and copies the result over using the `xmm0` register.

The same goes for `gByVal`: Clang:

```
gByVal(Foo):                          # @gByVal(Foo)
        push    rax
        call    fByVal(Foo)@PLT
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, rdx
        call    fByVal(Foo)@PLT
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, rdx
        pop     rax
        jmp     fByVal(Foo)@PLT
```

MSVC:

```
$T1 = 32
$T2 = 32
$T3 = 32
$T4 = 48
$T5 = 48
__$ReturnAddress$ = 80
input$ = 88
Foo gByVal(Foo) PROC                     ; gByVal, COMDAT
$LN4:
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 64                             ; 00000040H
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     rbx, rcx
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR $T3[rsp]
        movdqa  XMMWORD PTR $T3[rsp], xmm0
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T5[rsp]
        call    Foo fByVal(Foo)                ; fByVal
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR $T2[rsp]
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR $T4[rsp]
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movdqa  XMMWORD PTR $T2[rsp], xmm0
        call    Foo fByVal(Foo)                ; fByVal
        lea     rdx, QWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
        mov     rcx, rbx
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movdqa  XMMWORD PTR $T1[rsp], xmm0
        call    Foo fByVal(Foo)                ; fByVal
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 64                             ; 00000040H
        pop     rbx
        ret     0
Foo gByVal(Foo) ENDP                     ; gByVal
```

Granted, Clang can make use of the Itanium ABI, but MSVC still inserts unnecessary temporary variables and copies.

How can get MSVC to elide the copies? Is there something in the C++ standard that mandates MSVC to insert them?